# C++ trouble flipping a ppm image

Tags: c++, arrays, ppm

I successfully figured out how to read the rgb values from the ppm file and now i need to modify it. however when I flip the image (second set of for loops in readImg) it displays the exact same image. Does this have to do with the array being an unsigned char or is it still in the input stream. Any help would be great.

```
#include "finalproj.h"

int readImg(std::string header, unsigned char r[][HEIGHT], unsigned char g[][HEIGHT], unsigned char b[][HEIGHT])
{

int wid, hei, max;
int j= wid/2;
int k= hei/2;

std::ifstream fin;
fin.open("cs1a.ppm");

fin >> header;
fin >> wid >> hei >> max;

for(int col=0; col < wid; ++col)
{
    for(int row=0; row < hei; ++row)
    {
        r[col][row] = fin.get();
        g[col][row] = fin.get();
        b[col][row] = fin.get();
    }
}

for(int col=0; col < wid; ++col)
{
    --k;
    for(int row = hei/2; row < hei/2; ++row)
    {
        --j;
        r[col][row] =r[j][k];
        g[col][row] =g[j][k];
        b[col][row] =b[j][k];
    }
}

// mirrorHoriz(header, wid, hei, max, r, g, b);

saveImg(header, wid, hei, max, r,g,b);

fin.close();

return 0;
}
```

~
~

```
#include "finalproj.h"

int saveImg(std::string header, int wid, int hei, int max, unsigned char r[][HEIGHT], unsigned char g[][HEIGHT], unsigned char b[][HEIGHT])
{

std::ofstream fout;
fout.open("new.ppm");

fout << header << std::endl;
fout << wid << " " << hei << std::endl;
fout << max << std::endl;
for(int col=0; col < wid; ++col)
{
    for(int row=0; row < hei; ++row)
    {
        fout << g[col][row];
        fout << b[col][row];
        fout << r[col][row];
    }
}

fout.close();

return 0;
}
```

~
~

```
#include "finalproj.h"

int main()
{
int wid, hei, max;
unsigned char r[WID][HEIGHT], g[WID][HEIGHT], b[WID][HEIGHT];
std::string header;

readImg(header, r, g ,b);

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Why read then flip?  Why not just read the pixels in the flipped orientation?

Comment: @JohnZwinck isn't it more fun to do this with code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a mirror image about the x-axis `readImg(...)` should look like this:

```
if (hei >= 2)
{
  unsigned char tmp;
  for (int col=0; (col < wid); ++col)
  {
    for(int row=hei/2, k=row; ((k >= 0) && (row < hei)); ++row, --k)
    {
      tmp=r[col][row]; r[col][row]=r[col][k]; r[col][k]=tmp;
      tmp=g[col][row]; g[col][row]=g[col][k]; g[col][k]=tmp;
      tmp=b[col][row]; b[col][row]=b[col][k]; b[col][k]=tmp;
      //// same as
      //std::swap(r[col][row], r[col][k]);
      //std::swap(g[col][row], g[col][k]);
      //std::swap(b[col][row], b[col][k]);
    }
  }
}
```

The above approach starts at the center of the image and swaps row data while moving towards the edge. This approach would only work if `((hei % 2) == 1)`.

A recommended approach is to start at the edge; swapping top and bottom row data while moving towards the center:

if you are prefer **using an index**

```
if (hei >= 2)
{
  for (int col=0; (col < wid); ++col)
  {
    int i = 0;          // top
    int j = (hei - 1);  // bottom

    while (i < j) // swap top and bottom row data progressively
    {
      std::swap(r[col][i], r[col][j]);
      std::swap(g[col][i], g[col][j]);
      std::swap(b[col][i], b[col][j]); ++i; --j;
    }
  }
}
```

if you prefer **using pointers**:

```
if (hei >= 2)
{
  for (int col=0; (col < wid); ++col)
  {
    unsigned char *r0 = &r[col][0];
    unsigned char *r1 = &r[col][hei - 1];
    unsigned char *g0 = &g[col][0];
    unsigned char *g1 = &g[col][hei - 1];
    unsigned char *b0 = &b[col][0];
    unsigned char *b1 = &b[col][hei - 1];

    while (r0 < r1)
    {
      std::swap(*r0, *r1); ++r0; --r1;
      std::swap(*g0, *g1); ++g0; --g1;
      std::swap(*b0, *b1); ++b0; --b1;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: For the first set of code why is unsigned char temp used to read the array. Are unsigned chars of arrays not allowed to be used to change an index position?

Comment: @benjawmin Using `tmp` like I did in the first snippet is equivalent to using `std::swap` _(see comment in the code)_. The code doesn't change the index, it merely swaps the data at a given index with that of another.

Comment: @benjawmin For the second snippet, I used pointers but you can change this to swap index values like I did in the first snippet _(pointers are faster though..)_